# What is the advantage of using alphanumeric ID in URLs? Is it for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, identifier

I have been seen some of the reputed news portals are using the Alphanumeric ID in URLs to get extra benefits for SEO. And also they are doing well.

But I want to know about it that is there any benefit to use the alphanumeric ID in URLs? If there is so, please explain in details.

Comment: Where have you read that this is for SEO?   My guess is that using alphanumeric ids rather than just numeric ids allows them to make their URLs shorter.  I can't imagine it has anything to do with SEO.

Comment: Just I wanted to know that is it using for SEO purpose or others?

Answer (score 1):

No. Alphanumeric isn't good for SEO. It's better to use a permalink structure that is based on the post title, which ideally must contain the keywords (not necessarily to stuff it or overoptimize it).

Dynamic URLs with random alphanumeric characters won't do good in terms of SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if it would work, it would be an interesting approach... But i very doubt, that it makes any sence, specially at the current time.

Well ok, URL is coming from unified ressource locator (identifier). It means each url should be unique. For times Google was forcing to add to any url of Google News publishers an alphanumeric id. Currently this id is no longer required.

Imagine an example:

Google gets a search query like "best seo tutorial". Google starts a lookup in its index database and gets some urls containing /best-seo-tutorial/. On this place somebody could imagine, an id in the url could help Google to find and deliver certain result faster. But no. All urls, even all urls with the same slug /best-seo-tutorial/ are unique - namely because of domain. The domain brings the context in the game and serves as sufficient identifier for url slugs too.

So thats why i doubt, that any kind of id would bring any kind of SEO benefits.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the old requirement for inclusion in Google news. Until a few years ago publishers were required to use arbitrary digits in the URL if they wanted their articles to show up in news. [It was dropped as a requirement](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-news-drops-3-digit-url-rule-20962.html) in 2015 but many publishers still have the old URL structure. It had benefits then, but no longer.